# Prove statement about the roots of a monic polynomial, possibly using Rouché?

Tags: complex-analysis, polynomials, roots, holomorphic-functions, entire-functions

The question (a complex variables qual question from a few years back) asks:

Suppose that $$p(z) = a_0 + a_1z + \cdots + a_{n-1}z^{n-1} + z^n$$ is a monic polynomial with complex coefficients.  If $r$ is a root of $p$, prove that

$$|r| < \max\{1, |a_0| + \cdots + |a_{n-1}|\}$$

I proved this fact in two cases, one of which used Rouché's Theorem, but since I had to resort to more trivial algebra for the second case want to make sure that my proof isn't more complicated than it needs to be:

Call $A:=\sum_{i=0,\ldots,n}|a_i|$.

(1) **(Case A < 1):** then $$|p(z) - z^n|\leq A$$ on the circle $|z| = 1$ by the Triangle Inequality and $|z^n| = 1$ trivially on the same circle.  Since both functions are entire and $z^n$ only vanishes at the origin Rouché applies, whence $z^n$ and $(p(z) - z^n) + z^n = p(z)$ both have $n$ zeros within the unit disc.  If $|r| < 1$ then certainly $|r| < \max\{1, A\}$.

(2) **(Case A>= 1):** For sake of argument, suppose that $r$ is a root of $p$ such that
$$r > \max\{1, |a_0| + \cdots + |a_{n-1}|\} = A$$
Then $$|p(r)| = 0 = |a_0 + a_1r + \cdots +r^n|$$
One can apply the Triangle Inequality to obtain
$$0 = |p(r)| \geq |r||a_1 + a_2r + \cdots + a_{n-1}r^{n-2} + r^{n-1}| - |a_0|$$
whence
$$|a_0|>|a_0|/|r| \geq |a_1 + a_2r + \cdots + a_{n-1}r^{n-2} + r^{n-1}|$$
Repeated application of the same step results in
$$|a_0| + \cdots + |a_{n-2}| > |a_{n-1} + r|$$
whence, by one more application of the Triangle Inequality,
$$A > |r|$$ which is a contradiction of our selection criterion for $r$.

I'd really appreciate your insight.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If $|r|<1$, then there is nothing to prove. Thus, let us assume $|r|\ge 1$. Since
$$
a_0 + a_1r + \cdots + a_{n-1}r^{n-1} + r^n =0
$$
then
$$
r = -\frac{a_0}{r^{n-1}} - \frac{a_1}{r^{n-2}} - \cdots - a_{n-1}.
$$
By taking absolute values and using the triangular inequality, we obtain
$$
|r| \le \frac{a_0}{|r|^{n-1}} + \frac{a_1}{|r|^{n-2}} + \cdots + |a_{n-1}|.
$$
Finally, using that $|r|\ge 1$ (so that $\frac{1}{|r|}\le 1$), we obtain the required upper bound
$$
|r| \le |a_0| + \cdots + |a_{n-1}|.
$$

Comment: So we nearly don't need to invoke anything regarding the complex analysis. Nice answer!